# React Icon is declared but its value is never read .ts(6133)

Tags: reactjs, react-icons

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {BsLinkedin} from 'react-icons/bs'

    const HeaderSocials = () => {
      return (
        <div className='header_socials'>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com">BsLinkedin</a>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

I first ran `npm install react-icons --save`, however when I import BsLinkedin from `react-icons/bs` and try to call for it, I get the error `React Icon is declared but its value is never read .ts(6133).` Although I can still start my local host, the text `"BsLinkedin"` is displayed instead of the actual icon I want.

Comment: The way you write BsLinkedin make .tsx file understand that text not component. You could use something like {BsLinkedin} if it a variable or <BsLinkedin/> if it a component.

Answer (score 1):

What you are importing is an React component, so it can be displayed just like how you'd render a component like `<BsLinkedin />`

Therefore, you can get it to work properly by

```
import React from 'react'
import { BsLinkedin } from 'react-icons/bs'

const HeaderSocials = () => {
  return (
    <div className="header_socials">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com">
        <BsLinkedin />
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}
```

See the official documentation intro section of documentation here -- https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons